# Configuring Wacom Tablet for different programs

Tags: 14.04, command-line, wacom

In the windows Wacom drivers you can set different button mapps for different programs and I was wondering if this was possible in ubuntu in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all the people that are struggling with this problem. Here is a nice little wiki on how to set-up profiles for all your different programs e.g. GIMP, Inkscape, etc.

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tablet_Configuration